# Horizontal expandable list view in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, expandablelistview

I need to make an horizontal list view that expands on being clicked. What is the best possible way of achieving this ? Thanks !

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000702/recycling-views-inside-a-horizontal-scrollview-android/15025196#15025196) question as well. It also addresses similar issue. Thanks !

Comment: Nice One..! There is no any inbuilt component in Android. You have to Make your own. Either using Horizontal ScrollBar or Gallery..

Comment: @downvoter - Its nice if you write reason for down voting..

Comment: Maybe some images of what you want would help us understand what you mean...

Comment: @Orabîg is think it's obviously.

Comment: @biovamp : ok, sorry then. I must be the only one in the world thinking it's not, so I leave it for the rest of the population who understands the question...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to use setOnItemClickListener() and increase the size at runtime with setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height)).