# Recycling views inside a horizontal scrollview android

Tags: android, listview, garbage-collection, horizontalscrollview

I'm making an app with fairly complex UI. Its comparable to a horizontal list view that expands to a viewpager on being clicked. Presently, I've implemented this using the most basic approach. I simply inflate views inside a `horizontalScrollView` and inflate another subview with animation whenever user taps on any parent view.

This works perfectly fine and gives it a look of horizontal **expandable** listview. However, I feel this approach is highly inefficient since I keep on getting GC warnings almost every few seconds thereby reducing performance. And in this approach I'm not even recyling views like `listview` does.

My questions are:

- Is there any other efficient way of doing this ?
- How could I recycle views in my existing code like listview does?

Thanks!

(Please don't recommend using Gallery. My view is fairly complex)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other efficient way of doing this ?

Use `ViewPager` or the open source `HorizontalListView`, both of which use the adapter pattern.

Comment: How to make it expandable? Thanks !

Comment: @Infinity: I do not know what you mean by "expandable".

Comment: a subview slides out of it on being clicked like in `ExpandableListView`

Comment: @Infinity: Neither does that out of the box. You are welcome to take the source code for `HorizontalListView` and create your own `HorizontalExpandableListView` based upon it.